# Can you change the order events fire in Javascript for external libraries?

Tags: javascript, events

I am using a jquery plugin called: jQueryFontIconPicker. I am modifying this icon picker to also select image icons that the user can upload.

When the icon is chosen I use the .on('change') attached to the function that creates the jqfonticonpicker... the problem is that I am trying to manipulate the dom but cannot force my changes to take effect AFTER the plugins changes take effect.

Is there an elegant way to set sequencing?

```
var iconcats = { // these are just arrays listing the icons to use. they all work fine.
            'Library Icons': libicons,
            'My Icons': usericons
        };

        $('.iconpicker-input').fontIconPicker({
            source:    iconcats,
            emptyIcon: false,
            hasSearch: true,
            theme: 'fip-darkgrey'
        }).on('change', function(){
  // Do DOM changes here, replace icons with images.

            var target = event.target;
            var iconname;

            if($(target).hasClass('custom-icon-image'))
            {
                iconname = $(target).attr('title');
                alert('check sequence');
                $(target).closest('.icons-selector .selected-icon i').html('<img class="selected-icon-image" src="/site_repo/' + siteID +'/icons/' + iconname + '.png" title="' + iconname + '" />');
                $(target).closest('.icons-selector .selector').html('<p>test</p>');
            }
        });

});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post a working example of this code, it's not really clear what the problem is based on a snippet and a vague explanation.

Comment: You can most likely not change what the plugin does... Maybe if you give us what the actual problem is, we could give you an answer on how to get around it.

Comment: you need to create a promise, use your plugin inside, then use .then function to execute your code asynchroniously.

Comment: I believe the code I have above is sufficient for you to understand what I am hoping to accomplish. What I need to solve is I want my code to run (the what you see in the on change anon function.. AFTER the plugin updates the dom area I am trying to modify. I have updated and show more of what I am doing to update the dom... If you are familiar with the plugin mentioned, then the code I have posted will make sense. Im just trying to manipulate sequence of firing..  thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that there is no control over the sequence of execution of events, it seems to be browser controlled, so I ended up just modifying the plugin code myself. Not ideal, but solves the problem.